# how to pass the value of an encrypted variable from one cloud page to another?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

when I do it this way it works well but in the url it shows me the value of the variable

`SET @link = concat("https://cloudpage.com?subscriberkeym2=",@skey2)`

and the desirable thing is that it doesn't show that value or that it encrypts it,

but when I do it this way I get an error

`SET @link ="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123, 'subscriberkeym2',@skey2)=%%"                       Redirect(@link)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the `qs` as the context between the pages.

In the email to the subscriber:

`<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(123)=%%">link</a>`

In the first CloudPage -- retrieve the subscriber and send context from incoming email:

```ampscript
%%[

  var @sk
  var @qs
  var @fn
  set @qs = QueryParameter("qs") /* encrypted context */
  set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") /* system personalization string */
  set @fn = AttributeValue("firstName") /* sending DE column value */


]%%
<br>qs: %%=v(@qs)=%%
<br>sk: %%=v(@sk)=%%
<br>fn:  %%=v(@fn)=%%
<br><a href="%%=concat("https://pages.example.com?qs=",@qs)=%%"
```

In the second CloudPage -- retrieve the subscriber and send context the same way:

```ampscript
%%[

  var @sk
  var @fn
  set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") /* system personalization string */
  set @fn = AttributeValue("firstName") /* sending DE column value */

]%%
<br>sk: %%=v(@sk)=%%
<br>fn:  %%=v(@fn)=%%
```

Comment: Cool! CloudPagesURL() is limited to within a BU. Would passing on the qs params work across BUs? Cloudpage 1 in BU A, Cloudpage 2 in BU B?

Comment: I think so, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Tested & confirmed: It does work to pass encrypted qs on to another BU, likely even MC instance (no idea for what), and interpret it there. but: QueryParameter() looks at the encrypted _content_ of qs, not qs as a string. For example, qs contains a parameter jid, which you can surface using your approach. but QueryParameter  won't retrieve the encrypted context on page 1.  We can however do the intended thing, which is isolate the qs string using RequestParameter('PageURL'). Once we have that, it can be sent to other cloudpages and those read out things like the subscriberkey, the jobId etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link to cloudpage 1 using CloudpagesURL.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(12345))=%%">link to CP 1</a>
```

Send the email with this link to yourself for testing. This will add a job Id into your qs parameter.

===

Cloudpage 1 (pageId 12345):

accepts the link, isolates the content of qs parameter with some basic string manipulation. adds the result to another link.
in the example it is an href that has to be clicked, but you can use this in a redirect.

result is: CloudPage 1 passes on an encrypted GET-request to Cloudpage 2 which can decrypt the GET parameters out of the box using RequestParameter.
Cloudpage 2 can be in another BU.

```
%%[
SET @targetPage = "https://www.test.com" 
/* url of cloudpage 2. this can be in another BU */
SET @PAGEURL = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')
SET @occurrenceAmpersand = IndexOf(@PAGEURL,"&")
IF @occurrenceAmpersand > 0 THEN
    SET @urlTrimmedRight = Substring(@PAGEURL,1,Subtract(@occurrenceAmpersand,1))
ELSE 
    SET @urlTrimmedRight = @PAGEURL
ENDIF
SET @lengthUrlTrimmedRight = length(@urlTrimmedRight)
SET @startOfQS = IndexOf(@urlTrimmedRight,"=")
SET @startOfQSPlusOne = Add(@startOfQS,1)
SEt @deltaLength = Subtract(@lengthUrlTrimmedRight,@startOfQS)
SET @isolatedQS = Substring(@urlTrimmedRight,@startOfQSPlusOne,@deltaLength)

]%%
<br>PAGEURL: %%=v(@PAGEURL)=%%
<br>targetPage: %%=v(@targetPage)=%%
<br>isolatedQS: %%=v(@isolatedQS)=%%
<br><a href="%%=concat(@targetPage,'?qs=',@isolatedQS)=%%">send subscriber data to another page, encrypted</a>
```

CloudPage 2:

```
%%[
set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") /* system personalization string */
SEt @jid = RequestParameter("jid") /* an example for an encrypted parameter always found inside qs */

]%%
<br>sk: %%=v(@sk)=%%
<br>jid: %%=v(@jid)=%%
```

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this by using the following code for ampscript and it encrypts the value correctlyas "href" did not redirect me

`Redirect(CloudPagesURL(PassCloudPageID, "sk", @SubscriberKey))`

thank you very much for your help

Comment: You shouldn't pass around unencrypted subscriber keys.  You can substitute a redirect() instead of a href in my answer, depending on your requirements/flow.

Comment: the cloudpagesurl function encrypts the data, the user's email is not visible in the url            ```https://example.com/email?sk=02b332fb20660e462a6bcf3436d8d6df81ecfda478bff73f7e6cf17ca3047cea```

Comment: Ah, right.  Gotcha

Comment: you can take away the negative point of the answer so I can serve more people thanks

Comment: Edit your answer and that'll unlock it for upvotes and downvotes again.